# What is the package name for Microsoft office word?

Tags: ms-word, app-inventor

I'm trying to make an app that allows the user to put in information and then transfer the information over to Microsoft word to automatically organize it into an invoice.  However, I cannot find the information about the Microsoft word app in order to do this. This website http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/other/activitystarter.html states that you require the package name and class name, or the appropriate intent, in order to work an activity starter.
I'm using MIT App Inventor and I'm kind of new at this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the package/class name (online) for the application, you can't start an activity. Most likely that it is **not open source**, so it is not available for the public.

From http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html:

> These can be App Inventor apps created by you or others.   They can
>   also be apps like Camera and Maps that are pre-installed on the
>   device.  Or they be any app at all as long as you have the
>   **necessary** information to provide to the activity starter.

For example:

To start an acitivity for the camera use the package *android.hardware.camera2*. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

I don't know if you want to consider it, but you can also use **FusionTables**. The information you submit in your app will be inserted into a table in your Google Drive. (http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/pizzaparty.html)